# XCOM2 on Fedora: Can't find libcrypto.so.1.0.0

Tags: fedora, openssl, libraries, steam

I've installed XCOM2 via Steam on Fedora 26, but it didn't work. I manually executed the installed binary and got the error:

```
./XCOM2: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I then tried manually syslinking the system's (which is x64) version into `~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/XCOM 2/lib/x86_64` but then it complains that the ELF class is wrong (looks like my version is a 32-bit lib targetting i686?!).

Why do I have a 32-bit version of libcrypto in `/lib` in the first place and (more pertinently) how do I get XCOM2 to work? I'm relatively new to Fedora and have tried to solve this myself, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, an

```
ldd ./XCOM2
```

will show, which libraries do your binary want to link in. You will see, exactly which ones can't be found.

You can check the architecture of a shared lib with the command

```
file -szL /lib/libsomething.so.a.b.c
```

It will say, if it is an i386 or an amd64 library. The same is for your `XCOM2` binary.

The architectures should match. Although the `ldd` already shows, what exactly exists and what isn't.

Most distributions have at least a limited multi-arch support, what means, your system can have libraries and binaries coincidentally for multiple architectures.

Find the packages containing the missing libraries (on rpm-based distributions, it can be done with the `scout` tool, or deb-based ones with `apt-file`). Install them (on rpm, with `yum`, on debian, `apt-get`).

If the given libraries don't exist on your distribution, then you have to get them from an external source. However, manipulating the system libraries because a single binary is not useful.

Mostly, these libraries exist on a different version of the same distribution (on debian, you can find it on http://packages.debian.org, for other distros I don't know). Download the packages, extract them manually (on rpm, the command is: `rpm2cpio something.rpm|cpio -i -d`, on debian: `dpkg -x something.deb; tar -Jxvf data.tar.xz`), copy the required library files into the given directory.

With prefixing a binary by

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/here/are/my/additional/libs ./XCOM2
```

you can start `XCOM2` by giving this additional directory to the shared lib search path.

Comment: Thanks so much! After working out what libraries I needed with `ldd`, I managed to compile them from source and it hopefully will all work!